# gconf-editor like tool for kde

Tags: gnome, kde, gconf

I use some KDE apps ( Eg: konsole.) on a gnome-shell session, and I can't always get to the settings menu (due to global-menu malfunctions). So, I wanted another way of editing kde app settings without editing the configuration files stored in .kde directly. Is there a convenient application like gconf-editor (which works with gnome apps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a gconf-editor like application for the KDE.

Few Ubuntu forums links that are saying the same thing:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319966
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=955034